# How to update post with multiple images in django templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i have two models 1-post 2-postimage so the post can have multiple images so I'm having a trouble to update the post and its images in my templates

i did like upload multiple images when i create a post put i dont know how to do it with the update post
so  can any one show me how to do it or give me a tutorial link
Because I searched alot and couldn't find any tutorials

this is my models

```py
class Post(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    ch = [
            ('pvp','pvp'),
            ('Default','Default'),
            ('bedrock','bedrock')
        ]
    xch = [
        ('x1','x1'),
        ('x4','x4'),
        ('x8','x8'),
        ('x16','x16'),
        ('x32','x32'),
        ('x64','x64'),
        ('x128','x128'),
        ('x256','x256'),
        ('x512','x512'),

    ]
    vch = [
        ('1.7','1.7'),
        ('1.8','1.8'),
        ('1.9','1.9'),
        ('1.10','1.10'),
        ('1.11','1.11'),
        ('1.12','1.12'),
        ('1.13','1.13'),
        ('1.14','1.14'),
        ('1.15','1.15'),
        ('1.16','1.16'),
        ('1.17','1.17'),

    ]
    author =  models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField()
    mainimage = models.ImageField(null=True ,upload_to=thumbnail_upload_to)
    rpfile =  models.FileField(null=True, upload_to=file_upload_to)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    xnumber = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=xch, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ch, null=True)
    discord_id = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(
    HitCount, object_id_field='pk',
    related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    proved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)[:30]
    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if self.pk is None:
        saved_image = self.mainimage
        self.mainimage = None
        rpfile = self.rpfile
        self.rpfile = None
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mainimage = saved_image
        self.rpfile = rpfile
        if 'force_insert' in kwargs:
          kwargs.pop('force_insert')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']
    def get_absolute_url (self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': str(self.pk)})



class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.FileField(upload_to =in_post_images_upload_to)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if self.pk is None:
        saved_image = self.images
        self.images = None
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.images = saved_image
        if 'force_insert' in kwargs:
          kwargs.pop('force_insert')
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

Comment: Which one of these model do you want to update, the `Post` or `PostImage` model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django inline admin, The Django admin interface has the ability to edit models on the same page as a parent model. These are called inlines.
As the above models:

```
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin

from .models import (
    Post, PostImage
)

admin.site.register(PostImage)


class PostImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PostImage
    readonly_fields = ('id', 'post',)
    extra = 1


@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PostImageInline, ]
```

That will allow the user to add multiple images on the same page for editing or creating the Post.

Ref.: [Django Inline Admin](https://www.letscodemore.com/blog/django-inline-admin-with-examples/)

Comment: No I don't want it in my admin I want it in the templates?